# Modifying Connection String C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-connection

I am trying to modify a connection string with this code.

```
private bool ChangeEFConnectionString(string connStringName, string newValue)
        {
            try
            {
                //CreateXDocument and load configuration file
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

                //Find all connection strings
                var query1 = from p in doc.Descendants("connectionStrings").Descendants()
                             select p;

                //Go through each connection string elements find atribute specified by argument and replace its value with newVAlue
                foreach (var child in query1)
                {
                    foreach (var atr in child.Attributes())
                    {
                        if (atr.Name.LocalName == "name" && atr.Value == connStringName)
                            if (atr.NextAttribute != null && atr.NextAttribute.Name == "connectionString")
                            {
                                // Create the EF connection string from existing
                                EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
                                new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(atr.NextAttribute.Value);
                                //
                                var tg = entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString;
                                entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = newValue;
                                //back the modified connection string to the configuration file
                                atr.NextAttribute.Value = entityBuilder.ToString();
                            }
                    }
                }

                doc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
                //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

But it only works one time. i found it here https://bhrnjica.net/2011/01/30/handling-with-connection-string-at-run-time-in-developing-the-desktop-applications/ its the "Change connection string for Entity Framework at run-time"

I'm using forms and i have a combobox where i have a on SelectedIndexChanged that modifys a string variable and i want to switch betwene the 2 databases i have that contains different user data.

This is the 2 connection strings i am using

```
connection = "data source=FASTEC-ATTEST\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MigrateDBFaktura3;persist security info=True;user id=Faktura;password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
connection = "data source=FASTEC-ATTEST\\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MigrateDBFaktura5;persist security info=True;user id=Faktura;password=*******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework";
```

for now i have a button that run the ChangeEFConnectionString and a function that clears and then pupulate another cobobox with the user names from the server that is in use. but it will only change once then i need to restart the program if i want to connect to the outher.